# PHP, MySQL, FastCGI - best way to handle many queries

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to figure out the best way to handle db communication in PHP, MySQL setup through FastCGI and usig PHP-FPM; This is for a relatively heavy use site where there is anywhere from 100 to 1,000 SQL queries a second so I would like to make things as efficient as possible.

I am rewriting parts of the website and in the new code I am utilizing PDO and have the below class to handle DB queries and connections by doing database::insertEmployee($name, $SIN, $DOB, $position).  My concern is that with every query a new PDO connection is established.  Should I be trying to set up a persistent connection???

```
class database
{
    protected $dbh;
    protected static $instance;

    private function __construct()
    {
        try {
        // building data source name from config
            $dsn = 'mysql:=' . DB_Config::read('db.host') .
                   ';dbname='  . DB_Config::read('db.name');
            $user = DB_Config::read('db.user');
            $password = DB_Config::read('db.password');
            $this->dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
            $this->dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            //@TODO-KP: log and alert
            print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
            die();
        }

    }

    public static function getInstance()
    {
        if (!isset(self::$instance)) {
            $object = __CLASS__;
            self::$instance = new $object;
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }

    public static function insertEmployee($name, $position, $SIN, $DOB)
    {
        $dbi = self::getInstance();

        try {
            $sthEmployee = $dbi->dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO employees SET
                                                name = :name
                                                , position = :position
                                                , SIN = :SIN
                                                , DOB = :DOB'
            );

            $sthEmployee->bindParam(':name', $name);
            $sthEmployee->bindParam(':position', $position);
            $sthEmployee->bindParam(':SIN', $SIN);
            $sthEmployee->bindParam(':DOB', date('Y-m-d G:i:s', $DOB));

            return $sthEmployee->execute();

        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            //@FIXME-KP: log and alert
            print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "-- name [$name]";
            return '';
        }
    }
}
```

Any thoughts on most efficient approach would be very, very appreciated!

Kathryn.

Comment: I think the first step is to identify the actual queries being run. I'm not sure you're going to insert 1000 employees per second.

Comment: :) you are right, the insertEmployee is a dummy function. The application I am working with queries the DB for next content, logs  content viewed, logs click actions, etc.

Answer (score 0):

> My concern is that with every query a new PDO connection is established.

Well, verify your concern, because I would say this is likely not the case.

For performance reasons, take care you're using the mysql native driver under the hood as this allows extended metrics of the interaction from PHP with the database.

Also get a professional support plan from Oracle for Mysql, they have nice monitoring tools and very good support that should help you to get your database and PHP code ready for the traffic to handle.

Comment: I have both traced through and logged the getInstance function, and the isset(self::$instance) always equates to false and ends up going through the constructor.

Comment: yes but the new object is created, not the new connection. Mysql manages the connection pool.

Comment: however in the context of fastCGI I don't know if this is even possible that mysql reuses the previous connexions...

Comment: And that is exactly where I am stumbling... I am trying to understand how FastCGI handles database connections.  When a query is sent, is the process always: connect to DB -> send the query -> drop the connection?  And if that is the case wouldn't I have issues when retrieving lastInsertId?

Comment: FastCGI is completely unrelated to database connections. FastCGI is a connection protocol between the web server and a long-running PHP process (in your case PHP-FPM). Database connections do not flow through FastCGI.

Comment: @Kate: You might have got lost a little in the static global state you have in your program, however, in PHP, if you need a database connection (to the same server, with the same user), you need to connect *once* per request (in your code). That must not mean that this is full fresh database connection, *persistent connections* re-use from the connection pool. As *Francis* has outlined, FCGI / PHP-FPM is not specific to database connections, it is more [how you configure PDO](http://php.net/pdo.connections).

Comment: Francis and M8R, thank you for clarifying that... You are right that I mixed some things up which is probably why I couldn't find anything :P

Comment: Also, taking good coding practices and efficiency into consideration; Is using the database class a good approach?  Is checking for an instance with every query necessary?  I was reading "Pro PHP Application Performance: Tuning PHP Web Projects for Maximum Performance" and I deduced that every extra function, check, call, etc, could take a load on performance especially in high traffic apps.

Comment: Yes, the less you do the faster it goes. However at the end of the day you actually must profile your own mix of code where the bottleneck is. You can not optimize upfront well.